# google apps script, google picker for team drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-picker, google-drive-shared-drive

221/5000

Hello! At the moment I'm trying to implement google pikker for google team drive. This code works well for my google drive, but if you use this code for Google Team Drives, adding parameters

`.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)`

and

`.setSelectFolderEnabled(true)`

in the file display window is empty.

How I can fix it? 
Thank you!

[image]

it's should looks like it:

[image]

I think problem with OAuth 2.0.

There is good article about picker for team drive https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/picker, but there don't use this parameters:

`.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)`

`.setSelectFolderEnabled(true)`

Picker.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {
        width: 600,
        height: 425
    };

    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('picker', {
            'callback': function() {
                pickerApiLoaded = true;
            }
        });
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
            .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    function createPicker(token) {

        if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {

            var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
                .setIncludeFolders(true)
                .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
                .setSelectFolderEnabled(true)
                .setEnableTeamDrives(true);

            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .addView(docsView)
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                .hideTitleBar()
                .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2, DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
                .setOAuthToken(token)
                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                .setOrigin('https://docs.google.com')
                .build();

            picker.setVisible(true);

        } else {
            showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the
     * response object. For details on the response object, see
     * https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/result
     *
     * @param {object} data The response object.
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
        var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
        if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
            var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
            var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
            // Show the ID of the Google Drive folder
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = id;
            /**/

            google.script.run.searchFileInFoder(id);
            google.script.host.close();
            /**/
        } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
            google.script.host.close();
        }
    }

    function showError(message) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p id='result'></p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

code.gs

```
  /*Picker for сhoose folder*/
    function showPicker() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Picker.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select Folder');
    }

       function getOAuthToken() {
      DriveApp.getRootFolder();
      return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your docsView variable to be defined like this, so you include `google.picker.viewId.DOCS` inside the brackets of DocsView like this:

```
let docsView = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
                        .setEnableTeamDrives(true);
```

I tried to implement the code in the question above and I had few console errors and the picker didn't work properly. Probably it has to do with .setOrigin parameter. I can't say which part of your code is causing the error since I don't know your console logs. But anyways, below is my full createPicker() function which works for me:

```
function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
      var view = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS)
                        .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);
      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)
          .addView(new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
                        .setEnableTeamDrives(true))
          .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
          .addView(view)
          .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
          .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
          .setCallback(pickerCallback)
          .build();
      picker.setVisible(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I also just see a blank popup window when applying the google team drive enabling options.

Comment: Can you share what are the console errors logs that you have?

Comment: @timk: I edited my answer with the code I used inside createPicker() function which works fine for me.

Comment: why do you addView 3 times in the code above?

`addView(new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
                        .setEnableTeamDrives(true))
          .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
          .addView(view)`

Comment: @timk the picker shows me different tabs for each view. One view is for my regular drive files (not team drive). One view is just to allow selecting a whole folder from list of folders (also in normal drive). The third view is for the team drives which is separate from the regular drive.

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks!
It wasn't clear to me that you needed a separate view for Team Drive.. so because my GSuite Basic account doesnt' support Team Drive, that whole view probably wasn't loading.

Answer (score 1):

May be is too late to answer this but this was the solution using your code.

```js
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {
        width: 600,
        height: 425
    };

    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('picker', {
            'callback': function() {
                pickerApiLoaded = true;
            }
        });
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
            .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    function createPicker(token) {

        if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
            var Teamdrivesview = new google.picker.DocsView()
                //.setIncludeFolders(true)
                .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
                .setSelectFolderEnabled(true)
                .setEnableTeamDrives(true); 
            
            var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
                .setIncludeFolders(true)
                .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
                .setSelectFolderEnabled(true)
                .setEnableTeamDrives(true);

            var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .addView(docsView)
                .addView(Teamdrivesview)
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)
                .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
                .hideTitleBar()
                .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2, DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
                .setOAuthToken(token)
                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                .setOrigin('https://docs.google.com')
                .build();

            picker.setVisible(true);

        } else {
            showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the
     * response object. For details on the response object, see
     * https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/result
     *
     * @param {object} data The response object.
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
        var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
        if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
            var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
            var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
            // Show the ID of the Google Drive folder
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = id;
            /**/

            google.script.run.searchFileInFoder(id);
            google.script.host.close();
            /**/
        } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
            google.script.host.close();
        }
    }

    function showError(message) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Emilio can you please explain your code. Thank you.