# Attach PDF using Apps Script from Shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I need to attach a file to a mail using MailApp.sendEmail
Problem I'm running into is that I cannot attach anything from a shared drive, only from personal drive.
I'd like to use a shared drive to select which file to attach.

Anyone know if that's even possible?

Update:
This is the code that is used to open the picker, currently only working for the personal drive from the user running the script:

```
function createPicker(token) {
  if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
    var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
        // Instruct Picker to display all PDFs in Drive. For other
        // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
        .addView(google.picker.ViewId.PDFS)
        // Hide the navigation panel so that Picker fills more of the dialog.
        .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
        // Hide the title bar since an Apps Script dialog already has a title.
        .hideTitleBar()
        .setOAuthToken(token)
        .setCallback(pickerCallback)
        .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
        // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
        .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
            DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
        .build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
  }
}
```

I'd like to edit this so I can access a shared drive. I've found some stuff that uses GDrive API to access shared drives (also using picker) but I'm missing the experience to successfully edit it.

This is what I meant: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives

Comment: Welcome to SO, It would be helpful if you could show the code you tried so far

Comment: This is possible by using the Drive Advanced Service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Files and Folders in Team Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213373/accessing-files-and-folders-in-team-drive)

Comment: Hi, sorry for being unclear. I've updated my OP.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, should have searched some more. Sorry for wasting your time, thanks for your answers tho!

Solution I used that worked out for me:

[google apps script, google picker for team drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658325/google-apps-script-google-picker-for-team-drive)